# Using gitLab-CI for Qt-Projects

Tags: qt, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci

I want to use gitLab-CI for a Qt-project, but i can't figure out, what I need to do so. I understand, that the whole pipeline process takes place on the CI-Server, but how do I setup the needed requirements like the qt-environment?

### Solution:

Ok now I got it! You just use the Runner for it, if you do not have a Server, you can use a VM.

Comment: How did you get the QT environment setup though? I'm running CI Runner local with Docker.

Comment: I used this guide: https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/install/. I also used the runner local, but on a VM with Ubuntu. On the VM I did just setup the Qt environment, after that i was able to run jobs i defined in the yml-file of my git-repository.

Comment: Ok that answers my question. I'm going to have to preconfigure a VM image and/or a Docker image with the QT SDK that the rest of my dev team can leverage. Thanks for the quick response.

Answer (score 3):

## For GitLab.com

- The runners are already set up (shared runners).
- You need to use a Qt SDK Docker image or install it yourself:

  - Use `image: <image-name>` for `.gitlab-ci.yml`
  - Use `apt` or some other package manager (not recommended)
- Once you got a Qt SDK environment set up inside `.gitlab-ci.yml`, make sure to add a command to build/compile/run/test it.

## For non-GitLab.com

- The runners may or may not be set up, but you *do not* need to do any specific changes (other than using faster machines with bigger memory, etc for building in necessary).
- You need to use a Qt SDK Docker image or install it yourself:

  - Use `image: <image-name>` for `.gitlab-ci.yml`
  - Use `apt` or some other package manager (not recommended)
- Once you got a Qt SDK environment set up inside `.gitlab-ci.yml`, make sure to add a command to build/compile/run/test it.

## Other Helpful Comments

This is from Josh Peak's comment:

> Ok that answers my question. I'm going to have to preconfigure a VM image and/or a Docker image with the QT SDK that the rest of my dev team can leverage. Thanks for the quick response.

This answer is from ManuelP.'s question:

> Ok now I got it! You just use the Runner for it, if you do not have a Server, you can use a VM.